# C# used for Unity scripting, best practice about scope of variables

Tags: unity-game-engine, coding-style

I just started learning **Unity**, but I work as a software developer. 
Generally, in programming, it is a **good practice to make variables private** if that is possible.

But in Unity tutorial (made by unity) it is suggested to **make variables scope public so you can change it on the go** (the one that is useful to adjust as you go in Unity for testing).

Is it a good idea/Unity practice to make variables public, or should I stick to making them private?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the style that you are comfortable using. If you still want to have the variable show up in the inspector use the following attribute:
[SerializedField]

This should allow you to program the way you want along with having the functionality of the Unity inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Public is if you want to access this variable from other classes

Private makes it so it can only be used by the existing object

If you expand your class and make it extendable into child classes, only public variables will show up to the children, private variables/methods will not be available.

Best practice? It depends, if you are working on a team and you want to protect your variables/methods from being accessed unexpectedly, private is good. If you are a solo individual developer on the project it probably doesn't matter if you just use public.